# Can't get overflow to work when resizing a <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

So basically I'm working on a table that can dispose its rows with a nice animation. The problem is that I can't shrink a row beyond the point where its size is smaller than the size of its contents. Once the shrinking animation reaches the height of the text (I'm shrinking it vertically), it stops. Of course I looked for an answer on Google and Stack Overflow as well, and found quite a few, but I tried all of them with no success. I tried writing `overflow: hidden;` in the CSS, and all the other stuff that is claimed to solve this problem.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9hznp00s/7/) is my working example (sorry for not showing the code here, but it's easier to just link a working and editable example). Click the button to create a new table, then click the rows to make them go away.

I know this question has been answered elsewhere before, but those solutions don't seem to work for me.

Any ideas? I want the clicked row to shrink completely before getting deleted.

PS.: sorry if I'm being dumb, I'm new to web development.

PS2.: no jQuery please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update / change the lineheight like this

https://jsfiddle.net/9hznp00s/12/

```
function deleteRow(id) {
    if (typeof (id) === 'undefined') return;

    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    // Set the row's height and opacity to 0 (the changes are animated by the CSS)

    // I commented this out so it's easier to see the collapse effect
    //element.style.opacity = 0;

    element.style.height = '0px';
    element.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    element.style.lineHeight = '0px';
    element.style.opacity=0.0;

    // After the animation is done, remove the row form the HTML
    setTimeout(function () {
        element.innerHTML = '';
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }, 500);
}
```

or try one of these
https://jsfiddle.net/9hznp00s/8/

```
function deleteRow(id) {
    if (typeof (id) === 'undefined') return;

    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    // Set the row's height and opacity to 0 (the changes are animated by the CSS)

    // I commented this out so it's easier to see the collapse effect
    //element.style.opacity = 0;

    element.style.height = '0px';
    element.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    element.style.fontSize = '0px';

    // After the animation is done, remove the row form the HTML
    setTimeout(function () {
        element.innerHTML = '';
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }, 500);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9hznp00s/10/

```
function deleteRow(id) {
    if (typeof (id) === 'undefined') return;

    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    // Set the row's height and opacity to 0 (the changes are animated by the CSS)

    // I commented this out so it's easier to see the collapse effect
    //element.style.opacity = 0;

    element.style.height = '0px';
    element.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    element.style.fontSize = '0px';
    element.style.opacity=0.0;

    // After the animation is done, remove the row form the HTML
    setTimeout(function () {
        element.innerHTML = '';
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Resizing the text looks kind of weird... But if there's no other answer, I'll accept it though. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer, lineheight works much better but I dit not try or test, if there are any problems with other elements when applying this change to the elements

Comment: I think this is what you actually wanted.

Comment: This one has the same effect as the original that I posted. Maybe it's a compatibility thing, I'm on Safari.

Comment: I am on Google Chrome and it works like it should, the box fades out including the text and the box is resized but the text keeps its fontsize but now it does not stop at the text.

Comment: if you open the console in Safari, are there any notifications?

Comment: Nothing... Never mind though, I'm going with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9hznp00s/27/) (don't mind the style change). This works pretty well. Thanks!